# Div aligned to the right side of the page but cannot move left past a certain point

Tags: css, xhtml, html

My problem lies [here](http://untruth.webs.com/notes/folder.htm). My goal is to have the first set of divs, the notebook, always on the left of the page. This was easily accomplished. But now, trying to get the other set, the folder, to align to right right of the page and also display beside the notebook is a bit tricky.

So far the closest I have gotten to my goal is using absolute positioning. This would be fine except it causes a few problems. For example, the folder is ALWAYS linked to the right, which leads to problems when the window is resized narrowly. I doubt this is fixable using absolute positioning, but it's the best I could get.

Please help suggest better ways of doing this that actually work. So far I've tried other types of positioning, inline displaying, spans, and what not.  I'm not much used to using spans and possibly could have just used them wrong.

Comment: I've looked at your CSS, but it isn't clear from this question exactly what your desired behavior is. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'll try to be clearer next time. And, ObscureRobot, I tried to use the span tag to get the two sets next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `body` tag:

```
position: relative;
min-width: 1115px; /* you can adjust this slightly */
```

and then adjust some of your top positioning and you should have the effect you are looking for (as I interpret your question is to not have them overlap).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed, I would have never thought to use something like that.